# How to target only the current hovering div with jquery when there are many other divs with the same class?

Tags: jquery

How to target only current div (that I am hovering over) and not all divs with the same class using jQuery hover() function?

My code is something like this (I have many `div.video-item` elements on my website (it can vary for each page):

```
<div classs="video-item list">
    <a class="video-item-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>signup">
        <img class="video-item-image" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/001.jpg'; ?>">
        <div class="mouseover-element"><!-- --></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div classs="video-item list">
    <a class="video-item-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>signup">
        <img class="video-item-image" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/002.jpg'; ?>">
        <div class="mouseover-element"><!-- --></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div classs="video-item list">
    <a class="video-item-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>signup">
        <img class="video-item-image" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/003.jpg'; ?>">
        <div class="mouseover-element"><!-- --></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The JS is:

```
<script>
    $('a.video-item-link').hover(

      function() {
         // in
         $('a.video-item-link div.mouseover-element').show();

      }, function() {
         // out
         $('a.video-item-link div.mouseover-element').hide();
      }
    );
</script>
```

The style for `div.mouseover-element` is display: none; in default CSS

How can I target only the current div that my mouse is over? Right now when I mouseover over any `div.video-item-link` all 25 `div.mouseover` are shown. How to limit that only hfor my currently hovering div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `this`, which is the target of the event, along with jQuery traversal functions:

```
$('a.video-item-link').hover(function() {
     // in
     $(this).find('div.mouseover').show();
  }, function() {
     // out
     $(this).find('div.mouseover').hide();
  }
);
```

Though from your markup, it looks like you need `$(this).find('div.mouseover-element')`

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I will select your answer in a couple of minutes. Right now the system doesn't allow that. I have to wait.