# Hover only one element (active one)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a ecommerce site, and on products list when i hover one, al products got active state, like im hovering all of them, how to add hover only to one, and the other inactive with the same class, stay inactive, this is my code

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-hover">
    <p> SOME PHP CALLS HERE</p>
  </div>
  <p>some php here</p>
</div>
```

AND MY CSS:

```
.product-hover {
  display: none;
  background-color: #FEEEEE;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.product:hover .product-hover {
  display: block;
  line-height: 25;
}

.product {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: @Fred -ii : Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140111/how-to-target-only-the-current-hovering-div-with-jquery-when-there-are-many-othe

Comment: where are the products displayed? Please show more complete html

Answer (score 0):

What is applying the hover class? It would make more sense to use the CSS :hover psuedoclass rather than using Javascript to apply an explicit class. Sounds like the Javascript is applying the hover class to all elements with a specific class.